# ui slider visible but doesn't move

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-slider

I have the following code that works fine when I run it by itself in it's own html file.  However when I use as a part of my bigger webpage the slider is visible but does not move.

Here is my javascript

```
$("#slider").slider({

                            range: false,
                            min: 0,
                            max: 10, step: 1

});
```

HTML

```
<div id="slider"></div>
```

Also here are all my includes.  From what I gathered it must be a conflict with another js file.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.js" ></script>
 <script type='text/javascript' src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script> 

//the one above is the new one, that is references by the slider


    <script type='text/javascript' src='Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js'></script>


    <script type='text/javascript' src='Scripts/jquery.mobilemenu.js?ver=1.0'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='Scripts/si.files.js?ver=1.0'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.uploadify-3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/swfobject.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/fullcalendar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.simplemodal.js"></script>
```

Comment: `jQuery("#slider")` , try if this work's

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: no errors.  mohammad get the same issue.

Comment: Try removing all your JavaScript includes except jQuery and jQuery UI.

Comment: It seems there may be an issue elsewhere, because the code above seems to work fine in this fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/dFysr/

Comment: do you see any error logged in the console when you try to move the slider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the problem it's because I had my slider div inside of a table.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, thats what I am thinking...  It hardly matters where you put your slider div..

Answer (score 2):

Just in case it is a jquery conflict you can use..

```
var j=jQuery.noConflict();
j("#slider").slider({    
       range: false,
       min: 0,
       max: 10, 
       step: 1    
});
```

Comment: SCRIPT5007: Object expected  I get that error when doing that.

Comment: tried that.  The slider is working fine if I put a slide: and the something like alert('hello') it works.  the problem is its not making it large enough.

Answer (score 1):

In my case didnt move because I didnt add link to jquery ui css :)